# How can I hide a DIV's based on number both on page load and onClick of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a span that generates a number, if its 0 I want to hide/show two divs, if its anything else then the opposite.

First it needs to apply when the page loads, then whenever a specific button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<button class="button">Add to cart</button>
<span class="catInStock">0</span>

 <div id="slave">SOLD OUT</div>
 <div id="slave-1">Some form</div>
```

CODE:

```
var n = $("span.catInStock").text();

if (n == 0) {
     $("div#slave").hide();
     $("div#slave-1").show();
   } else {
     $("div#slave").show();
     $("div#slave-1").hide();
   }    

  $('.button').click(function () {
   if (n == 0) {
     $("div#slave").hide();
     $("div#slave-1").show();
   } else {
     $("div#slave").show();
     $("div#slave-1").hide();
   }
 });
```

I don't think running it twice is the best option, something much slimmer would make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can use `toggle()` with a boolean argument to hide/show

```
function displaySlaves( ){
     var n = $("span.catInStock").text();
     $("div#slave").toggle( n=='0');
     $("div#slave-1").hide( n !='0' );
}
/* page load*/
$(function(){  
   displaySlaves( );
   $('.button').click(displaySlaves)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.button').bind('load click', function () {
   if (n == 0) {
     $("div#slave").hide();
     $("div#slave-1").show();
   } else {
     $("div#slave").show();
     $("div#slave-1").hide();
   }
});
```

Comment: `button` won't register a load event, most html elements don't